# How to use upstream and reverseproxy nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 2 node server at cdn1.xxvideo18.com and cdn2.xxvideo18.com and main server at cdnxx.xxvideo18.com
How can i use upstream and reverseproxy? I try config like bellow but it return defaul 404 page

```
upstream main {
    server cdn1.xxvideo18.com;
    server cdn2.xxvideo18.com;
}

server {
    server_name cdnxx.xxvideo18.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://main;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdnxx.xxvideo18.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdnxx.xxvideo18.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = cdnxx.xxvideo18.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name cdnxx.xxvideo18.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Found it
I have to add port for upstream

```
upstream main {
    server cdn1.xxvideo18.com:443;
    server cdn2.xxvideo18.com:443;
}

server {
    server_name cdnxx.xxvideo18.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://main;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdnxx.xxvideo18.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdnxx.xxvideo18.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: If you find a solution to your issue, please don't edit it to the question but add it as an answer.

Comment: Sory, I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it I have to add port for upstream

```
upstream main {
    server cdn1.xxvideo18.com:443;
    server cdn2.xxvideo18.com:443;
}

server {
    server_name cdnxx.xxvideo18.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://main;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdnxx.xxvideo18.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cdnxx.xxvideo18.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```